# How does BuildSiteMap() Method work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, sitemap

I am working on CustomSiteMapProvider that i have Derived from
StaticSiteMapProvider.
I have override BuildSiteMap() Method to Build Sitemap.It is working
properly,
But Can anyone tell me How it is works internally? I have found that It
is getting called more than one time.
Why is this executing more than one?

How many times does this method get executed?

I have read many artical, But I didnot find any discussion about
internal working of BuildSiteMap() Or why it gets executed more than
once?

Any idea? Any artical Or link will be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have any relationship to JustDecompile but this should help you out alot

http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please read [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.staticsitemapprovider.buildsitemap.aspx)

It says

> The BuildSiteMap method is called by the default implementation of the **FindSiteMapNode**, **GetChildNodes**, and **GetParentNode** methods.
>
> If you override the BuildSiteMap method in a derived class,
> **ensure that it loads site map data only once and returns on subsequent calls**.

So at some point, system calls FindSiteMapNode, GetChildNodes, and GetParentNode methods. And then BuildSiteMap will be called as well.

Here is another [MS engineer's post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/10/10/asp.net-crash-_2d00_-crazy-looping-in-a-sitemap.aspx)